# question regarding message internal updation

Tags: settings

i am using Samsung galaxy A8, my question is that only one of conversation is converted into like "whats app" in internal message app, while rest of the conversations just as simple as other mobile phones conversation.. how can i convert all the conversations into above mentioned pattern? 
i mean one of the person conversation in my internal mobile app is showing that MSG is delivered and MSG is read and it sounds interesting so how can i make other conversations n this pattern

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're talking about SMS messages. SMS messages don't have delivery and read indications. The one contact that acts differently is using the same message app as you, so the app isn't sending SMS message to that contact, but using its own system, which does have delivery and read indications.

If you want features like an instant message system, you have to use the same instant message system that your friends have. You can send SMS to any phone, but it's an older technology and it doesn't support those features at all.